# Peak virtual memory: 537 megabytes error in quartus ii

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I wrote the following code within Quartus II version 14.1:

```
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
ENTITY light IS
     PORT ( x1, x2 : IN STD_LOGIC ;
           f : OUT STD_LOGIC ) ;
END light ;
ARCHITECTURE LogicFunction OF light IS
BEGIN
        f <= (x1 AND NOT x2) OR (NOT x1 AND x2);
END LogicFunction ;
```

but when timing simulation I got the following error:
Peak virtual memory: 537 megabytes error in quartus ii

Any solution??/

Comment: Your code XOR  is valid VHDL, and analyzes, elaborates and simulates. Added [tag:quartus] tag.

Comment: timing simulation with no clock and just concurrent statements doesn't make much sense. What exactly do you expect TimeQuest to do with your code?

Comment: What do you mean by timing simulation ?  Can you share more information on how this error occurs ?

Comment: I mean behavioral verification

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this error after testbench. You may have missed, periods ('.') before some of your instantiated module's signal names.For instance,

```
enable UUT(clock(clock_tb),reset(reset_tb),Rled(Rled_tb));
```

should be,

```
enable UUT(.clock(clock_tb),.reset(reset_tb),.Rled(Rled_tb));
```

I solved the same problem with this solution.
I hope this could help you.